# DKIM on Google Workspace not setup yet DKIM check PASSES?

Tags: dkim

I have a domain that's using Google Workspace that doesn't have DKIM authentication enabled. Even though DKIM isn't set up, emails sent from that domain arrive in other inboxes and **pass** the DKIM check.

Digging into the headers, they're all showing a DKIM signature from a subdomain of gappssmtp.com, yet, the envelope-from and from headers are all set to the sending domain, not gappssmtp.com.

I feel like I'm missing something straightforward to explain this, but I can't wrap my head around it. How does this work? If Google Workspace used a default DKIM signature, wouldn't the envelope-from have to match to lookup the selector to pass the recipient mail server dkim check?

Comment: DKIM does not require the domain of the signer to be the same as the domain of the sender.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/591655/what-domain-name-should-appear-in-a-dkim-signature for some interesting reading on this subject.

Comment: Good reading, thanks. It begs the question though, assuming google’s reputation is better than my domain, what’s the benefit to enabling DKIM authentication in google workspace?

Comment: *" what’s the benefit to enabling DKIM authentication in google workspace?"* - DKIM with a domain aligned to From header is kind of needed to make DMARC work (alternatively: aligned SPF, but better have both because both have their drawbacks where they fail)